# Remove glow from button

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I remove the glow around the button? I can't seem to find it here. The code has been copied from other resources. Thank you.

```
<div class="row clearfix">
   <div id='media-controls' style="width:100%; height:60px; text-align:center;">
   <button id='play-pause-button' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'>Play</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
button {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.pause { background-position:-19px 0; }
.stop { background-position:-38px 0; }
.volume-plus { background-position:-57px 0; }
.volume-minus { background-position:-76px 0; }
.mute { background-position:-95px 0; }
.unmute { background-position:-114px 0; }
.replay { background-position:-133px 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XEWhk/413/

Comment: im not seeing a glow in jsfiddle.  what kind of glow is it?

Comment: what glow are you talking about? I can't find any glow in your button in jsfiddle, can u provide a screenshot?, did you tried replacing <button> tag to <input type="button"/>?

Comment: @josh well, upon clicking the button, grey shade glow appears

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll have to add this to the button:

```
outline: 0;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEWhk/416/)**

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove the glow around the button you can use the following css:

```
box-shadow:none;
```

Comment: You can see that it's not a box-shadow or anything other. It is the focus outline which some of the browsers doing defaultly.